# PostgreSQL + lexical definition of GROUP_P

Tags: postgresql

Where can I find lexical definitions of all PostgreSQL keywords / tokens, like GROUP_P?

Comment: There is a keywords.[ch] file in the parser directory (symlinked from various places) There is also a compliancy statement at the end of The Fine Manual.

Comment: @wildplasser Thanks. I think the list is in the `parser/kwlist.h`, right? Why some of keywords have `_P` endings?

Comment: I don't have the faintest idea. Could be some naming convention for meta-types. Where did you find it ? You could grep the source tree for it.

Comment: @wildplasser I found it in `/src/include/parser/kwlist.h`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP_P` is not a keyword, it's a symbol in the context of the C compiler and it doesn't have lexical significance outside of the C source code.

In this declaration from `parser/kwlist.h`:

```
PG_KEYWORD("group", GROUP_P, RESERVED_KEYWORD)
```

it is the first argument "group" that is the keyword, the 2nd argument GROUP_P being typically an enum field or a #define (it's up to the includer).

The header file `src/include/parser/keywords.h` provides a struct type `ScanKeyword` that can be directly mapped to the PG_KEYWORD macro, field by field:

```
typedef struct ScanKeyword
{
    const char *name;           /* in lower case */
    int16       value;          /* grammar's token code */
    int16       category;       /* see codes above */
} ScanKeyword;
```

For a concrete example of use, see how ECPG does it in  `src/interfaces/ecpg/preproc/keywords.c`